# How to use K-fold cross validation in TensorFlow

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgCea.png)

I'm using TensorFlow 2.3 and i want to use k-folders, does anyone know how to use it?

Does anybody know if that's the right way to train my model?

if not, can you answer me the right way. Thanks

Comment: Is it OK if l don't set a checkpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from this [blog](https://www.machinecurve.com/index.php/2020/02/18/how-to-use-k-fold-cross-validation-with-keras/)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)

for train, test in kfold.split(inputs, targets):

  # Define and fit the model
  model = ...
  model.fit(...)
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.